# How to create a relaunch function in ExtJS 4.1?

Tags: javascript, extjs

I want a relaunch method that basically destroys the existing extjs application and then launches it again. window.load is not an option for various reasons. I tried viewport.removeAll() and looping through Ext.WindowManager and destroying all components. But after launch some components are misbehaving and looks like the cleanup hasnt happened properly.

Comment: Could you please elaborate why window.load is not an option; so we know what exactly should stay and what should be destroyed? Could you furthermore elaborate on which components are misbehaving? Did you try to log both components to console, to find out what exactly is wrong with them?

Comment: So this application is a child application. Window.load will reload the whole parent application which is not ideal. The child should be able to destroy itself and then re-initialize everything to show the latest data. The problem is I am not able to destroy the controllers, stores and models because of which the application reaches an inconsistent state.

Comment: What do you mean, "child application". How did you overcome the "one viewport per window" limitation?